# How to specify argument type in lambda?

Tags: python, lambda

For usual functions, you can annotate the type as follows

```
def my_function(arg1: int)
```

How do I do this in lambda?

```
lambda a: int, b: int : a+b
```

gives a syntax error.

Comment: If Python tells you that `'int' object is not subscriptable`, it means that you are asking it to call `[]` on an `int`. Telling that these objects are lists will not change anything, since they still are actual integers. Besides, specifying the type of arguments in Python is, I believe, nothing more than a tool to produce self-documented code. The Python interpreter, as far as I know, is not expected to have some particular behaviour when coming across an object whose type has been declared.

Comment: Type annotations don't fix TypeErrors.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Man that was a harsh edit

Comment: @Rightleg there were two completely different questions; as there were answers to both, I picked the one that didn't seem to be a dupe of other *"how do I reduce"* questions.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Gonna have to delete all the answers related to that part, then

Comment: Apologies for the poorly asked question

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The question was: "How to specify argument type in python lambda?".
Although the other answers are good, they do not provide answer to this main question.

The answer is: you cannot.

From the [PEP specification of function annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/#lambda):

> lambda 's syntax does not support annotations. The syntax of lambda could be changed to support annotations, by requiring parentheses around the parameter list. However it was decided [12] not to make this change because:
>
> It would be an incompatible change.
> Lambda's are neutered anyway.
> The lambda can always be changed to a function.

For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33833896/7051394

Answer (score 0):

For your particular problem, let's see how reduce works:

```
lambda a, b : a[0] + b[0]
```

Here, `a` is the result of previous iteration and `b` is the current element.

Now, let's see your program:

```
functools.reduce(lambda a, b : a[0] + b[0], [[0,1], [2,3]])
```

Details:

```
iter #1: a = [0,1], b = [2,3], so, a[0] + b[0] = 0 + 2 =3
```

It works.

But when you do:

```
functools.reduce(lambda a, b : a[0] + b[0], [[0,1], [2,3], [4,5]])
```

Details:

```
iter #1: a = [0,1], b = [2,3], so, a[0] + b[0] = 0 + 2 =3 
iter #2: a = 3, b = [4,5], so, a[0] + b[0] = Error, as you can't subscript an integer `3` (3[0] > Error).
```

Error regeneration:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> a[0]
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>       TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

---

You can get the desired result with:

```
a = [[0,1], [2,3], [4,5]]
print sum(map(lambda x:x[0],a))
```

Or,

```
print sum(i[0] for i in a)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question though. It was "how to specify argument type in python lambda", not "how can I do this".

Comment: @Rightleg, what do you think now? the answer is updated.

Comment: It's not a bad answer, it just does not answer the main question. Though it does address OP's problem, so I took my downvote back.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `reduce` will compute

```
result1 = func(x1, x2)
result2 = func(result1, x3)
...
```

your function accepts two `lists` and returns a number, so on the second call the function fails (unless you only provide two elements).

To be able to use `reduce` the function should accept two arguments and return a value **of the same type of the arguments** because the output of the function will be re-used as input at next iteration.