# Python lambda type hint in pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm to develop python scripts.

I have a list of class and want to sort this list by a class property.

However, when I use:

```
results: list[HotelInfo] = get_result()
results.sort(key=lambda x: x.price)
```

PyCharm's type hint shows that "x" is of type "any" and can't get class property.

Even if I set `x: CLASS_NAME`, the lambda seems doesn't display correct type.

[image]

How can I solve this problem in PyCharm?

Answer (score 0):

As [Martijn Pieters♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) points out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33833896/14492466) you can type hint a callable object and pass that as your function.

```
results: list[HotelInfo] = get_result()
get_price: Callable[[HotelInfo], int] = lambda hotel: hotel.price
results.sort(key=get_price)
```

This works for me in a local example and PyCharm recognizes the types.

```
strings = ["Hello World", "Goodbye World :(", "Cookies"]

func: Callable[[str], int] = lambda s: len(s)
print(sorted(strings, key=func))
```

Comment: It's not work, I use your example `... ] = lambda hotel: hotel.price` , pycharm still show the `hotel` is `any`